# Is it possible for a droplet to condense in the middle (bulk rather than boundary) of the vapor without impurity?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, non-equilibrium

As a rule of thumb, vapor condensation usually happens at the interface between the system and the heat reservoir. Now, according to my analysis below, it is the only way for vapor to condense, which implies the near impossibility of condensation in the bulk of vapor.  :

As the temperature drops, within the vapor system, whose thermodynamic behavior can be described by a canonical ensemble, energy is favored over entropy. That is, the energy should escape from the system to the heat reservoir to create a large entropy overall. This means that the system has the tendency to evolve into the low energy configuration when the temperature drops. Thus, for such a phase transition to take place, the passage of energy from the system to the reservoir is crucial. The case for vapor is unique in that its only access to the heat reservoir is on the surface, while for other systems, such as the Ising model, it has access to heat reservoir (the phonons, for instance) within the bulk so that we can see "bubbles" of broken symmetry, domain walls, forming inside the bulk. At the interface between vapor system and the heat reservoir, the mechanism for such a transfer of energy is the conversion of kinetic energy of vapor into the phonons of the reservoir. In the bulk of vapor, however, there is no direct way for the energy to be transferred. Classically, the energy released by forming a droplet can only be carried to reservoir by vapor. This process is extremely inefficient, and its explicit mechanism is obscure. Quantum mechanically, it should be possible that the release of energy is in the form of radiation, where the "radiation background" plays the role of a heat reservoir. Clearly, these two passages of transferring energy to the reservoir should be negligible compared to the mechanism taking place at the interface. So, in any realistic cases, condensation of droplets never happens in the bulk without impurity.

It remains to be checked whether such an analysis is physically well-founded and consistent with the experiment.

Comment: [Homogeneous nucleation from the vapor phase](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/145/21/211702/196311/Overview-Homogeneous-nucleation-from-the-vapor)

Comment: @JohnRennie  Did they observe nucleation out of the bulk?

Comment: @JohnRennie I did some quick keyword searches, and the paper didn't even mention reservoir, so I believe it failed to go in the right direction whatever conclusion it reached.

Answer (score 1):

Condensation at pre-existing nuclei is one way that the phase change proceeds. There is another way, as follows:

For the case of water vapor in air without pre-existing nuclei like dust particles where heat is being extracted from the mix, the random thermal motion of the air and water molecules will occasionally furnish an ensemble of water molecules which itself serves as a condensation nucleus.

It takes time for this random process to occur, and in the meantime, the temperature of the air/water vapor mix continues to fall *below that of the condensation temperature* and the water vapor becomes *subcooled* as it waits for statistics to furnish a nucleus. While subcooled, the latent heat of vaporization/condensation is removed from the water molecules *in advance of the impending phase change* which are thereby primed for instant condensation, which will occur at a rate *which is not limited by the rate of heat transfer out of the vapor and into the cold air*.

Comment: Yes, but I still believe even in the case os supercooling the nucleus production at the interface would dominate over bulk production unless interface production is prohibited by certain experimental method, for example by applying some organic film that repulse the water molecule.